# How to concatenate child elements when a different child element name matches

Tags: python, xml, xslt

Okay here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have an XML document that came from a CSV file of directory paths and security groups.  I would like to take the Group element and its children from a node that has a matching Path element and copy it to the previous node.  Here's an example:

```
<root>
    <Folder>
        <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RW</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Modify</Permission>
        </Group>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RO</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Read & Execute</Permission>
        </Group>
    </Folder>
</root>
```

Okay that's what it looks like now.  Note how the Path element on both nodes is the same.  What I want is for it to look like this:

```
<root>
    <Folder>
        <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RW</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Modify</Permission>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RO</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Read & Execute</Permission>
        </Group>
    </Folder>
</root>
```

The second node is gone, and the Group element and its children have been added to the previous node.

I'm fairly new to this kind of stuff, I'm comfortable with some programming and scripting in general, but not sure the best way to accomplish this.  I've seen that XSLT can possibly do what I'm looking for, but what I want it to actually do is take the input XML file, make the changes, and then give me an output XML file so that I can then take it and display it on a webpage in a tree with jsTree.  I've also looked at Python's ElementTree for processing the XML, but I'm not quite sure where to begin with that to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: A combination of an identity template/transform and Muenchian grouping should get you real far. Search on those 2 things and give it a try.

Comment: Also, if you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor, search on `xsl:for-each-group` instead of Muenchian.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll do some more research on XSLT.  I just wasn't sure if that was a good way to actually change the file, or only for display.  Looks like I'll need to find some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFolderByPath" match="Folder" use="Path"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "Folder[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kFolderByPath',Path)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Folder">
  <Folder>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "Path | key('kFolderByPath',Path)/*[not(self::Path)]"/>
  </Folder>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the (corrected for well-formedness) provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <Folder>
        <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RW</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Modify</Permission>
        </Group>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
        <Group>
            <Account>Shared_Data_RO</Account>
            <FullName></FullName>
            <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
            <Permission>Read &amp; Execute</Permission>
        </Group>
    </Folder>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <Folder>
      <Path>\\path\to\folder\_Shared Data\</Path>
      <Group>
         <Account>Shared_Data_RW</Account>
         <FullName/>
         <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
         <Permission>Modify</Permission>
      </Group>
      <Group>
         <Account>Shared_Data_RO</Account>
         <FullName/>
         <AccountType>GROUP</AccountType>
         <Permission>Read &amp; Execute</Permission>
      </Group>
   </Folder>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this does what I want it to do.  Now to figure out the implementation part of it.  Cheers!